# How do I change a form to use URL arguments?

Tags: php, search

My form currently takes the user to usersearch.php but there are no arguments with the data in the URL.

How can I go from this:

```
usersearch.php
```

To this?

```
usersearch.php?username=myAwesomeUsername
```

This is my script:

```
<? $user=$_POST["user"]; ?>
<form name="form" action="usersearch.php" method="post">
Username: 
<input type="text" name="user" value="<?echo($user)?>">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<fieldset><!--30-->
<?
$query1="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '".mysql_real_escape_string($user)."%' ";
echo("<hr color='red'>Username Results: $user<br><br>");
if(!$user == "")
{
$result1=mysql_query($query1,$con);
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_object($result1))
{
echo "Username: [".$row1->username."]<br>";
echo "User level: [".$row1->level."]<br>";
echo "User status: [".$row1->status."]<br>";
echo "User email: [".$row1->email."]<br>";
echo "User Bio: [".$row1->bio."]<hr>";
}
}else{
Echo "";
}
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: ... didnt try get method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the ?username= part on the URL, you need to change your form method to GET:

```
<form name="form" action="usersearch.php" method="get">
```